# Stop Blur event when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide ssn or other sensitive information in a textbox using JQuery events.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/af4wqmuy/)

```
 $('#txtMasked').keyup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    if (val.length > 4) {
        this.value = val;
    }
    if ((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        val = val.substr(3);
    }
    if (val.length > 5) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
        val = val.substr(5);
    }
    newVal += val;
    this.value = newVal;
});

$('#lnk').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#txtMasked').attr('type') === 'password') {

        $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'text');
        $(this).text('Hide');
        $(this).prop('title', 'Hide');
    } else {
        $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
        $(this).text('Show');
        $(this).prop('title', 'Show');
    }
    return false;
})

var show = function (ev) {
    $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'text');
    $('#lnk').text('Hide');
    $('#lnk').prop('title', 'Hide');
},
     hide = function (ev) {
         $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
         $('#lnk').text('Show');
         $('#lnk').prop('title', 'Show');
     };

$('#txtMasked').focus(show);
$('#txtMasked').blur(hide);
```

When focus event is triggered, the text is unmasked and it can be masked back by either  triggering the blur or link event.

When focus is triggered and the link is clicked, blur is also triggered. As a result, it confuses the link click event, thus the text is never masked.

I've search the internet and I can't find a way to stop both events from triggering at the same time.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079264/blur-event-is-triggered-instead-of-click), but it didn't work in my situation.

Please can anyone help?

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code snippet to your script.

```
 var is_blur=false;
 $(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target.id!='lnk'){
      is_blur=false; 
    }
 });
```

Change 'lnk' click event to following.

```
$('#lnk').click(function (e) {
    if(is_blur){
      is_blur=false;  
      return;
    }                

    if ($('#txtMasked').attr('type') === 'password') {
        $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'text');
        $(this).text('Hide');
        $(this).prop('title', 'Hide');
    } else {
        $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
        $(this).text('Show');
        $(this).prop('title', 'Show');
    }
    return false;
})
```

Change hide function to following.

```
hide = function (ev) {
         $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
         $('#lnk').text('Show');
         $('#lnk').prop('title', 'Show');
         is_blur=true;
     };
```

Hope these will help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/af4wqmuy/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('#txtMasked').keyup(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
   var newVal = '';
   if (val.length > 4) {
     this.value = val;
   }
   if ((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
     newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
     val = val.substr(3);
   }
   if (val.length > 5) {
     newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
     newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
     val = val.substr(5);
   }
   newVal += val;
   this.value = newVal;
 });

 $('#lnk').click(function(e) {
   if ($('#txtMasked').attr('type') === 'password') {

     $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'text');
     $(this).text('Hide');
     $(this).prop('title', 'Hide');
   } else {
     $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
     $(this).text('Show');
     $(this).prop('title', 'Show');
   }
   return false;
 })

 var show = function(ev) {
     $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'text');
     $('#lnk').text('Hide');
     $('#lnk').prop('title', 'Hide');
   },
   hide = function(ev) {
     $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
     $('#lnk').text('Show');
     $('#lnk').prop('title', 'Show');
   };

 $('#txtMasked').focus(show);
 $('#txtMasked').blur(function(e) {
   try {
     if (e.relatedTarget.id != 'lnk') {
       hide();
     }
   } catch (error) {
     hide();
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="mask-wrapper">
   <input id="txtMasked" type="Password" value="000-30-0009">
   <a id="lnk" class="linkbutton btn-link" ToolTip="Show" href="#" >Show</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that will stop blur event in click on link.

```
$('#lnk').click(function (e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     $(this).off("blur");
    if ($('#txtMasked').attr('type') === 'password') {

        $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'text');
        $(this).text('Hide');
        $(this).prop('title', 'Hide');
    } 
    else  {
        $('#txtMasked').attr('type', 'password');
        $(this).text('Show');
        $(this).prop('title', 'Show');
    }
    return false;
})
```

Comment: That didn't work, the blur event needs to be stopped by triggering the click event.

Comment: Ok let me check once again

Answer (score 0):

You can check if #lnk is the focused element before triggering `hide()` when the blur event happens.

```
$('#txtMasked').blur(function() {
        if (!$("#lnk")==$(document.activeElement)) {
            hide();
        }
    });
```